# will_paginate causes ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination

In our rails 3.2.8 app, the will_paginate causes ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error when clicking next page or another page after page 1. Here is the error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in LeaseBookingsController#show

Couldn't find LeaseBooking with id=search_results

Parameters:

{"page"=>"4",
 "id"=>"search_results"}
```

The search_results is a custom action in controller:

```
  def search_results
    @lease_booking = LeaseBooking.new(params[:lease_booking], :as => :roles_search)   
    @lease_bookings = @lease_booking.find_lease_bookings.paginate(:per_page => 40, :page => params[:page])
  end
```

find_lease_bookings is a method in models to retrieve the lease_booking record. The error is only with will_paginate. In gemfile there is:

```
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'
```

Any solution to solve the paging issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue today and wasted hell lot of time. And here is the reason.

"If your form's action is POST (or any other HTTP method) then the search term won't be applied to subsequent page links. In other words, when you follow the "Next page" or any other page link, the search parameter(s) would be lost."

Check out this link.
https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/Simple-search

So the solution is use GET in place of POST.

Comment: @user938363
Hey man I might sound silly... but i really need credits here. 
I answered bit late but don't you think my answer is correct?